# Add/Remove a Class Every 15 seconds using jQuery and stop on hover.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not great at jQuery and I'm stumped here, I'm trying to make a jQuery carousel that essentially rotates every 15 seconds automatically and stops on hover.

Right now I have this for the HTML:

```
<section id="featured">
   <div id="hero">
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rsz_shutterstock_323582282.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rsz_shutterstock_246059269.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rsz_shutterstock_342971345.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rsz_shutterstock_327686162.jpg)"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap clearfix" id="latest-wrap">
        <div class="clearfix" id="latest">
            <h5 id="the-latest"><span>Hot This Week</span></h5>
            <a href="/get-all-nine-quicktips-here/" class="">
            <article class="featured-article clearfix">
                <h4><span class="fa finance-101"></span>finance-101</h4>
                <h2 class="featured-title">Our Best Financial Tips to Watch On The Go</h2>
            </article>
            </a>        
            <a href="/how-to-throw-the-perfect-wedding-shower/" class="">
            <article class="featured-article clearfix">
                <h4><span class="fa fun"></span>fun</h4>
                <h2 class="featured-title">How to Throw the Perfect Bridal Shower</h2>
            </article>
            </a>    
            <a href="/watch-the-full-series-of-ytf-with-dennis-kneale/" class="">
            <article class="featured-article clearfix">
                <h4><span class="fa finance-101"></span>finance-101</h4>
                <h2 class="featured-title">If You're Reading This It's Not Too Late</h2>
            </article>
            </a>                
            <a href="/watch-the-full-season-of-mr-and-mrs-adventure-here/" class="">
            <article class="featured-article clearfix">
                <h4><span class="fa motivation"></span>motivation</h4>
                <h2 class="featured-title">Watch One Couple Travel the World on $1k a Month</h2>
            </article>
            </a>                                                    
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's what I have for jQuery...

```
$("li.categories").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});

$("#featured #hero .slide").eq(0).addClass("current");
$("#latest a").eq(0).addClass("current");

$("#latest a").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("#featured #hero .slide.current").removeClass("current");
    $("#featured #hero .slide").eq($("#latest a.current").index()-1).addClass("current");
}, function(){      
    $(this).removeClass("current");
});
```

Currently on hover it adds "current" in both places and stops and that's fine, but, I'd like for it to do this automatically every 10 seconds.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Where do you try and set the timer?

Comment: Have not got that far yet. 

I'm familiar with the idea of doing --

    setInterval(function(){
      /// stuff
    }, 5000);

but not sure how to make it cycle through the child elements correctly.

Comment: Take a look at setInterval.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp and probably .animate

Comment: Hmm I do get that, I tried doing this http://pastie.org/private/1oor6vwht6zzjwk6rd9qug but it seems to just add it to all of them, and, take it away -- it's the cycle part that I don't get. I need it to add it to each element once at a time and then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, try this:

Add this:
`var loopCarousel = true;`

When binding the hover, set the loopCarousel to false, set it to true again when not hovering. Add this function to your javascript and replace "your_selector" with the element being displayed.

```
function start(counter){
  if(counter < 10000 && loopCarousel){
    setTimeout(function(){
      counter++;

      $("your_selector").mouseover();

      start(counter);
    }, 10000);
  }
}
start(0);
```

Comment: Unless I messed up it looks like that just adds current and takes away current on all of the elements every 10 seconds -- which is what I also achieved with http://pastie.org/private/1oor6vwht6zzjwk6rd9qug. I need it to add it to one, take it away, add it to the next, repeat.

Comment: Quote "Currently on hover it adds "current" in both places" thats because you're using a selector that returns several objects instead of one. $("#latest a") will return all <a> under the div with id "latest". Maybe it's a good idea to make a JSFiddle with your whole code to make it easier to understand.